# VBA6 Syntax and OPOS Printer OCX Driver in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, opos

I'm using a "OPOS" printer and Access 2007, and I'm trying to get some access VBA code interact with the driver.

So far I got this VBA6 program that I'm trying to chew into Access VBA:

Form1.frm:

```
VERSION 5.00
Object = "{CCB90150-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719}#1.0#0"; "OPOSPOSPrinter.ocx"
Begin VB.Form Step1 
   BorderStyle     =   1  'fixed
   Caption         =   "Step1: ""Hello OPOS"" is printed "
   ClientHeight    =   1590
   ClientLeft      =   45
   ClientTop       =   330
   ClientWidth     =   3795
   LinkTopic       =   "MDIForm1"
   MaxButton       =   0   'False
   MinButton       =   0   'False
   ScaleHeight     =   1590
   ScaleWidth      =   3795
   StartUpPosition =   3  'Windows default value
   Begin VB.CommandButton cmdPrint 
      Caption         =   "Print Now"
      Height          =   450
      Left            =   1155
      TabIndex        =   0
      Top             =   525
      Width           =   1515
   End
   Begin OposPOSPrinter_CCOCtl.OPOSPOSPrinter OPOSPOSPrinter1 
      Left            =   3120
      OleObjectBlob   =   "Step1.frx":0000
      Top             =   960
   End
End
Attribute VB_Name = "Step1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
' Step 1： "Hello OPOS" gets printed

Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()

'send a string to the printer using method PrintNormal
'vbCrLf is VisualBasic standard newline
    OPOSPOSPrinter1.PrintNormal PTR_S_RECEIPT, "Hello OPOS" + vbCrLf

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()

    With OPOSPOSPrinter1
        'open device
        .Open "Unit1"

        'Claim exclusive access
        .ClaimDevice 1000

        'enable the device
        .DeviceEnabled = True
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    With OPOSPOSPrinter1
        'stop device
        .DeviceEnabled = False

        'Release exclusive access
        .ReleaseDevice

        'Done with the printer
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Also

This other file is included: [OposAll.bas](http://read.pudn.com/downloads125/sourcecode/windows/activex/530810/Include/OposAll.bas__.htm)

...as can be seen in the VBA project file:

```
Type=Exe
Form=Step1.frm
Module=OPOS; ..\..\..\..\Include\OposAll.bas
Object={CCB90150-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719}#1.0#0; OPOSPOSPrinter.ocx
IconForm="Step1"
Startup="Step1"
HelpFile=""
Title="SamplePrint1"
Command32=""
Name="SamplePrint1"
HelpContextID="0"
CompatibleMode="0"
MajorVer=1
MinorVer=0
RevisionVer=0
AutoIncrementVer=0
ServerSupportFiles=0
VersionCompanyName="MECS"
CompilationType=0
OptimizationType=0
FavorPentiumPro(tm)=0
CodeViewDebugInfo=0
NoAliasing=0
BoundsCheck=0
OverflowCheck=0
FlPointCheck=0
FDIVCheck=0
UnroundedFP=0
StartMode=0
Unattended=0
ThreadPerObject=0
MaxNumberOfThreads=1

[MS Transaction Server]
AutoRefresh=1
```

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to translate this into working Access VBA code.

My questions may seem silly but keep in mind I don't know either VBA6 nor Access 2007 VBA. But working with the DLL version was rather easy and I thought this would be a doable one too.

**1)** Silly question: What does this piece of code stand for?
Is it initializing some object? Access seems to dislike the `OPOSPOSPrinter1` part, is there another way to get this done in Access?

```
   Begin OposPOSPrinter_CCOCtl.OPOSPOSPrinter OPOSPOSPrinter1
      Left            =   3120
      OleObjectBlob   =   "Step1.frx":0000
      Top             =   960
   End
```

**2)** This is maybe the most important question: **Is there a saner way to communicate with an OCX driver from Access 2007 VBA?**

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a reference? or adding it as an activex control to an access form?

Comment: If you could point me to a how to about doing that with a driver that would pass as an answer. My googling skills suck or it's way too late here but I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

As I found in [MS website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918574), in Access 2007 you need to summon the ActiveX registering dialog in some obscure way:

```
Open a trusted database, or enable macros in the database.
Press CTRL+G to open the Immediate window.
Type the following code, and then press ENTER.

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRegisterActiveXControls
```

Next, I registered my exotic OCX control and got it listed as `OPOS POSPrinter Control 1.13.001 [Public, by CRM/RCS-Dayton]`.

After that, I added the newly registered control from the equally hidden Insert ActiveX button:

[image: IMHO MS employees use their OS backdoor to lol at desperate users who try to find things in the Ribbon®]

Once the control was added to my form, I proceeded to add the code for loading and unloading the driver:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    With OPOSPOSPrinter1
        'open device
        .Open "Unit1"

        'Claim exclusive access
        .ClaimDevice 1000

        'enable the device
        .DeviceEnabled = True
    End With

End Sub


Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    With OPOSPOSPrinter1
        'stop device
        .DeviceEnabled = False

        'Release exclusive access
        .ReleaseDevice

        'Done with the printer
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

As you can see, it didn't change at all in comparison to the original VBA6 form. Oh, and this syntax: `WITH <resource> (Body) END WITH` is just the VBA equivalent to C# `using` or the brand new `try (<autoclosable>)` in Java. So when you say `WITH OPOSPOSPrinter1` you are pointing to the activex control you just added. Check the name Access picked for it.

Importing the `opos.bas` was straightforward, probably because the Ribbon® wasn't involved at all in the process. In the code editor right click the project tree and click "Import...". The `.bas` files are imported as "Modules" verbatim, go figure. Maybe because it's just a bunch of variable definitions.

The print command also compiles unchanged:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    OPOSPOSPrinter1.PrintNormal PTR_S_RECEIPT, "Hello OPOS" + vbCrLf
End Sub
```

I haven't yet tested the monstruosity but I lightly promise I will update after I gather feedback from the device.

Finally, to answer my own silly question. The syntax in my question **1)** is VBA6's way of declaring a new control. Access seems to be doing it somewhere else.